# .emacs.d and site-lisp directory

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following two questions about emacs

1. In my .emacs.d directory there is an empty directory called auto-save-list. What is that for ?
2. I have create a elisp directory in my home directory on my linux machine where i place .el files. In my .emacs i have `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp")`
   Now,I have heard of .emacs.d/site-lisp directory. Im confused about the difference between site-lisp and my own elisp directory. Can someone please explain.

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read about `auto-save-list` here:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Recover` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> Emacs records information about interrupted sessions for later recovery in files named `.saves-PID-HOSTNAME' in the directory `~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/'.  This directory is determined by the variable `auto-save-list-file-prefix'.  If you set `auto-save-list-file-prefix' to `nil', sessions are not recorded for recovery.

You may be slightly confused about `site-lisp` -- the only standard directory by that name is not intended to live under a user's home directory (typically it lives at `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp`), and the only special thing about it is that Emacs will include it in the `load-path` list by default.

The intention, as the name suggests, is that libraries which should be available to *all* users on a given machine can be placed in that directory.

By contrast, the `~/elisp` directory you've created will not be available to anyone else.

Read more here:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Init File` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: +1 Good answer.  Maybe for comparison look at `/usr/bin` (system / OS binaries) vs `/usr/local/bin` (binaries installed locally by the system admin) vs `/home/you/bin` (your own binaries or scripts).  On modern Unices a lot ends up in `/usr/bin` because that's where the package manager installs stuff, too; on a traditional / old-school "hand-built" system, these additional packages would be compiled and managed locally and installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation phils, really helpful :).triplee, your analogy to the unix filesystem is also very good,many thanks ! :)