# What does emacs 'site' stand for?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm a beginner of emacs. when i try to config my emacs, i googled a lot of examples. most of them have a site-lisp directory.

My question is why not use my-lisp for self maded lisp files and use vendor-lisp for other people's site.

And what things should site-lisp direcotry contain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`my-lisp` and `vendor-lisp` are perfectly fine directory names for organising your personal elisp configuration and libraries.

"site" means "this computer", and so the `site-lisp` directory is for elisp which should be available to all users of the computer.

Similarly to [.emacs.d and site-lisp directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777239/emacs-d-and-site-lisp-directory/10777412) (follow for more details), I get the impression that you might be asking about having a `site-lisp` directory within your user-specific configuration, which would be contrary to this naming convention, and possibly a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks, i guess "site" stands for "this computer". my guess is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look around, there's also `python-site` and `ruby-site`. They are used by other packages from the package management to install `.el` files in a directory where emacs finds them at load.